# Call multiple funtions with single onClick in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, button, input, user-controls

This is my profile settings page: [Code](https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-varahamihira-dbhco?file=/src/UserInfo.js)

My buttons already call `onClick` function, but i wanna add `saveInfo` to my "save" button.

I just noticed that after clicking "save" the only field that remains saved is `First Name`, can you explain to me why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I adjusted your code for this to work properly.

Here is an updated sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-kapitsa-kznoi?file=/src/UserInfo.js

I extracted all of your additional code so it would be easier for me to debug, which is why you won't see some of the code in your original example.

Quite simply, the issue was that you were rendering an empty `<input>` when saved was not true.

If you want to send your saveInfo simply set the value of each input (when saved isn't true) to the value of your saveInfo.

I left comments within to help understand.